# Is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 text color broken?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio

I'm trying to move over to Visual Studio from Eclipse, and I want to bring a similar color scheme with me. But when I change the colors in the options, nothing seems to be changing. This is more than just an aesthetic thing, the different colors make reading the code quickly much easier. It doesn't seem like the colors can be changed, other than basic stuff like line numbers and comments.

Comment: Exactly which setting are you changing? Does Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors not work? Why can't you just get used to the VS colors?

Comment: Going to that path changes some things, I can change the base text color, and the color of the line numbers, but nothing more specific. The problem with the base VS colors is they don't have nearly as much variety as Eclipse does. Where in eclipse I can actually use the colors to tell what different bits of code are, in VS nearly all my code is just plain white. A few things show up as blue, but I can't use it to actually help me read the code the way I can in Eclipse. It makes big blocks of code much harder to read.

Comment: Are you sure VS is set up correctly for C++? If I go down the Display items list in that window I can find all the C++ stuff. Even by default VS should highlight various parts of your code in different colors. It seems like you're in the general text editor.

Comment: I actually have no idea if it's set up correctly to do c++. Now when I go to the display items list, I can *see* the c++ stuff. It just doesn't do anything when I change a setting.

Comment: Make sure `Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Database` is `FALSE`